# How to break out of a while loop in C#. Break not working

Tags: c#, while-loop, break

I can't seem to break out of this `while` loop with the break statement. Here is my code:

```
while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("What is 1 + 1?");
            int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (answer != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong answer. Press enter to get your next sum");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            else if (answer == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Well done. Press enter to get your next sum");
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("What is 1 + 3");
        int answer2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: When you check that `answer != 2` in the `if` branch, what are the possible values for `answer` in the `else` branch? Hint: there's only one :-)

Comment: You’re making a test for nothing here. If `answer != 2` fails, then it equals 2, so you can just `else` branch out.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine for me too ;)

Comment: your code works for me too..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you enter a number different than 2 you actually read another line which you do not process:

```
if (answer != 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong answer. Press enter to get your next sum");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Your confusion could be because of this line. Change it to:

```
if (answer != 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong answer. Press enter to get your next sum");
}
else{
    Console.WriteLine("Correct answer");
    break;
}
```